# 12factor way of logging to logstash

Tags: logging, logstash, 12factor

12factor says,

> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of
>   its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage
>   logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream,
>   unbuffered, to **stdout**.

Advantage would be, we don't have to configure different logging endpoints for different environment(dev/prod), unhandled exception written to **stderr** won't be missed.

I have some scripts in Python and Node.js which already logs to stdout/stderr and I don't want to modify those scripts for centralised logging.

So, how do I make these logs parsed into structured data and collected by logstash(including multiline errors).

In AWS stdout/stderr from Lambda or Beanstalk are captured by CloudWatch. So, if that's possible then there should be a way to do the same with logstash.

Comment: there's the [stdin input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-stdin.html) for logstash you can use as a start.

Comment: Its just the keyboard input right? But I want to capture the stream of `stdout` and `stderr` from a program.

Comment: If I remember right, you can use pipes between two program to pass the output of one to the stdin of the other. That's what I was thinking when talking of the stdin plugin.

Comment: Yes I figured it out but used TCP input and piped to it like `python stdout_logging.py 2>&1 | nc -q 1 localhost 9500` now figuring out how to capture multiline stack trace as a single message. And also @baudsp when you say to use stdin is it like running separate Logstash instance for each programs? Is it OK to do that?

Comment: `stdin is it like running separate Logstash instance for each programs` Yes it's the case. Since logstash is quite heavy (full JVM), it's not really a good idea, elastic usually advise to use a shipper (like filebeat) to move logs to a centralized logstash